# Get a sub-object for every object in JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have JSON that is a list of county objects with several year sub-objects. The format is like this:

```
{
county1: {
  "2007": {
    "data1": 5,
    "data2": 58
  },
  "2008": {
    "data1": 12,
    "data2": 63
  },
},

county2: {
  "2007": {
    "data1": 75,
    "data2": 3
  },
  "2008": {
    "data1": 9,
    "data2": 8
  },
}

}
```

Is there an easy way in javascript to return a similar structure, but with only a single year for each county i.e. 2008?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

Consider your data as **data** variable and design the way you want your new data to be structured

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val] = data[val]['2008']
    return acc;
}, {})
```

OR

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val] = {'2008':  data[val]['2008']}
    return acc;
}, {})
```